# Invert if, have tried multiple ways. cannot find error in code

Tags: java, arrays, loops, if-statement, boolean

when I run this code I get the error,

```
   at javaapplication1.JavaApplication1.bigger(JavaApplication1.java:32)
```

(the inver if warning), however I have tried everything I can think of. I'm not sure what I'm missing here in order to have it compile.

```
 public static boolean bigger(int x, int y)
   {
    int biggerNum =0;
    int numBigger = 0;
    int [] data = new int[MAXVALUES];
    for(int curIndex = 0; curIndex < data.length-1; curIndex++)
    {
       if (bigger(data[curIndex],data[data.length-1]))
       {
           numBigger++;
       }
       else 
       {
        return false;
       }   

     }

   }
```

Comment: Please provide the exact error you are getting

Comment: The error I'm getting is at the top of the segment. Including the exception in main thread.

Comment: @DrexDand No, this is just part of your error/warning or whatever it is.

Comment: No this is the error, I'm getting a inverted if warning which I stated and that error. That is it. Nothing else.

Comment: Wher is MAXVALUES constant defined.

Comment: The most important question is: what is this code supposed to do?

Answer (score 2):

You probably have an infinite recursion, since your method ignores the input integers, creates a new array and makes a recursive call to iteself in the loop.

It's unclear what this method is supposed to do, but the way you are doing it is clearly the wrong way.

Comment: So I simply have to provide user data so it is saving the correct thing?

Comment: @DrexDand I have no idea. Can you explain the expected behavior of this method?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is trying to suggest that you do this:

```
public static boolean bigger(int x, int y)
   {
    int biggerNum =0;
    int numBigger = 0;
    int [] data = new int[MAXVALUES];
    for(int curIndex = 0; curIndex < data.length-1; curIndex++)
    {
       if (!bigger(data[curIndex],data[data.length-1]))
           return false;
       numBigger++;
     }

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `bigger()` method won't compile because not all code paths return a value. Your method requires a `boolean` return value (`true` or `false`). Add a default return value at the end of the method.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly post your error statement and the purpose of the function.

Above functions shows that the function is running in infinite loop and there is no significance of variable x and y.
and there is no variables are defined in int [] data = new int[MAXVALUES];

Answer (score 0):

You have to "**invert if statment**" or in other words "**flip operands of the binary operator**". You use this when you want to check the equality of two objects.

from `if (A != B)` to `if (!A.equals(B))`

for instance:

```
int A = 10;
int B = 20; 
if(!A.equals(B)){
System.out.println("A is not equal to B");
}else{
System.out.println("A is equal to B");
}
```

Declaration from NetBeans 8.2 document:

**public boolean equals(Object obj)**

Indicates whether some other object is "equal to" this one.

The equals method implements an equivalence relation on non-null object references:

It is reflexive: for any non-null reference value x, x.equals(x) should return true.

It is symmetric: for any non-null reference values x and y, x.equals(y) should return true if and only if y.equals(x) returns true.

It is transitive: for any non-null reference values x, y, and z, if x.equals(y) returns true and y.equals(z) returns true, then x.equals(z) should return true.

It is consistent: for any non-null reference values x and y, multiple invocations of x.equals(y) consistently return true or consistently return false, provided no information used in equals comparisons on the objects is modified.

For any non-null reference value x, x.equals(null) should return false.
The equals method for class Object implements the most discriminating possible equivalence relation on objects; that is, for any non-null reference values x and y, this method returns true if and only if x and y refer to the same object (x == y has the value true).

Note that it is generally necessary to override the hashCode method whenever this method is overridden, so as to maintain the general contract for the hashCode method, which states that equal objects must have equal hash codes.

Parameters:
obj - the reference object with which to compare. 
Returns:
true if this object is the same as the obj argument; false otherwise.